# How to hard-code a given camera to a particular USB Port

Tags: python, linux, opencv, camera, nvidia-jetson

consider a schenario where i am connecting 2 cameras to 2 usb ports the camera i connect first will always come in stream 0 for code below where as i want the stream 0 to always read from a specific usb port.

```
import cv2
vc1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vc2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
vc3 = cv2.VideoCapture(4)
```

I want to hard code each camera to a specific usb port in python so no matter in what order the cameras are connected the camera from usb port 1 should always come in a specific stream and same for all streams.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find USB serial port with Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57745554/find-usb-serial-port-with-python-script)

Comment: no it doesn't finding usb serial is easier i can even use dmesg --follow
consider a schenario where i am connecting 2 cameras to 2 usb ports
the camera i connect first will always come in stream 0 for above code where as i want the stream 0 to always read from a specific usb port.

Comment: ***" i want the stream 0 to always read from a specific usb port."***: Then you are off, it's not the ability of a user to decide which port number a specific hardware is bound to. You have to define this at OS level,  ask at [unix.stackexchange.com/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)